# Training loss remained almost unchanged during training

Tags: pytorch, nlp

I am training a model.
This is my code to train the model.

```
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=args.learning_rate)
criterion = InfoNCELoss(temperature=0.1)
scheduler = optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, 1.0, gamma=0.1)

log_iter = 100

for e in range(1, args.epoch + 1):
    model.train()
    t0 = time.time()
    total_train_loss = 0

    for i, batch in enumerate(train_dataloader):

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        sentence1_embedding, sentence2_embedding = model(batch["sentence1"], batch["sentence2"])
        train_batch_loss = criterion(sentence1_embedding, sentence2_embedding, batch["sentence1_label"], batch["sentence2_label"])

        total_train_loss += train_batch_loss.item()
        train_batch_loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        scheduler.step()
```

This is my training loss:

[image]

Training loss remained almost unchanged during training.

Please help me to solve this.

Thank!

Answer (score 1):

Your `step_size` argument of [StepLR](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR.html) is too low, thats why learning rate decreases after each batch and becomes around zero. You can increase `step_size` or make `scheduler.step()` call once per epoch, not per batch.

```py
for e in range(...):
    ...

    for i, batch in enumerate(train_dataloader):

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        train_batch_loss = ...
        train_batch_loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    scheduler.step()
```

Comment: I used with step_size = 10 and 100. But training loss still remained almost unchanged during training.